# How to embed gcc and gcov command in expect script

Tags: gcc, expect

I wanted to embed gcc and gcov command as part of expect script..

I tried as..

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
send ":gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage c.c\r"

send ":gcov c.c\r"
```

But it doesnt run and execute the commands.

Any insights to this? Thanks.

---

The problem I have is I am not sure how can I embed the command at the right place. All I know was there is a given test cases as below :-

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn $env(SUBJECTS_SRC_DIR)/vim -u $env(HOME)/.vimrc $env(TESTS_SRC)/copy1
expect "copy1"
sleep 1
send ":se lines=24\r"
send ":se columns=80\r"
send ":redir >> move_2.1.1.out\r"
send "$"
send "\007"
send "5h"

send "\007"
send ":redir END\r"

send ":wq\r"
expect
exit -onexit {
interact
}
```

This is contained in a specific file named testfile. Once this testfile is executed in Perl script, an output is generated.

Something like below:

```
$IN_DIR/$SCRIPT_FILE;

$outfile = "$OUT_DIR/t$scriptCounter";
```

I tried to put the expect command which you have suggested earlier in a separate file named and passed to a new variable named...`$MY_FILE` in `$IN_DIR`.

And then, i passed `$IN_DIR/$MY_FILE`;

but it doesnt do anything. The .gcno files are not executed either so thus .gcov.

Answer (score 1):

Expect is useful for *interactive* programs, not for command-line utilities. If you want to just execute `gcc` and `gcov` as part of expect script, do this:

```
exec gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage c.c
exec gcov c.c
```

BTW, running `gcov` without first running the executable is futile: you need to *produce* the runtime coverage data before you can analyze it.